# Why is Google Analytics showing old event categories?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

For some reason, when I look in Google Analytics, the events that are being registered all have event categories that do not exist anymore in my Google Tag Manager.

I configured the event categories as 'click' when I first started using GTM, but changed these categories later so that they were more informative. I published the most recent version of my workspace and if I look at the settings the event categories are correctly displayed with the new names. GTM settings thus appear to be OK.

Also, when I test my website using the tag assistant in Chrome the tag details linked to my events are correct:

```
Type - Google Analytics: Universal Analytics
Firing Status - Succeeded
Non-Interaction Hit - false
Enable overriding settings in this tag - false
Category - 'plan'
```

As you see, the category is registered as 'plan' and not as 'click'.

So how can it be that Google Analytics is still registering events from my website visitors with 'click' as event category, even though it is deleted from the settings? Any idea where I should look? I don't know how to troubleshoot his problem further, so I'm unsure what other details I should share about the issue.

Comment: Always add id and version number for your container as custom dimension. We do this, and we always see a substantial minority (several percent) of users who still receive an older container version, presumably the effect of proxy caching servers and the like.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, thank you. I will make sure to do this in the future. For now, the issue I'm encountering is much larger than the substantial minority you describe, with I'm guessing up to 90% of the data coming in wrongly.